# Do 2 things when IF is true DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to find either a work-around for my current statement or a better way to do this all together.  I need to set the bundle_id but, once it's set, I don't want the formula changing it.  I tried if(isblank(OB1_excel_log[bundle_id]) but it wouldn't let me use that. so I created another column called Assigned next to my bundle_id and figured I would change the value from blank to a 1 once I updated my bundle_id and next time the formula ran it would skip all the rows with a 1 in the Assigned field.  Here's the DAX formula

```
bundle_id = if(isblank(OB1_excel_log[Assigned]),CALCULATE(min(Bundles[bundle_id]), filter(Bundles, OB1_excel_log[Dr Acct #] = Bundles[dr_account_no] && Bundles[Active]="Yes")) && OB1_excel_log[Assigned]=1)
```

It works until I put that extra action on the end

```
&& OB1_excel_log[Assigned]=1
```

Thoughts on how I can perform that additional action ?  Or a better way to set the bundle_id without using the 2 columns?  Thanks in advance

Comment: bundle_id is a calculated column?

Answer (score 1):

After formatting your DAX properly at https://www.daxformatter.com you can immediatly see what's going wrong. Your *extra action* belongs to the *else* section of the IF clause and does't make much sense.

```
bundle_id =
IF (
    ISBLANK ( OB1_excel_log[Assigned] ),
    CALCULATE (
        MIN ( Bundles[bundle_id] ),
        FILTER (
            Bundles,
            OB1_excel_log[Dr Acct #] = Bundles[dr_account_no]
                && Bundles[Active] = "Yes"
        )
    )
        && OB1_excel_log[Assigned] = 1
)
```

Comment: I understand that the formatter placed it in the else section because it can't be where it's at but it's not an else.  I need it to happen along with the previous action.

Comment: YOU put the extra action just before the final closing bracket, which is the Else clause. The formatter just made this error clearly visible.

Comment: I think we are running in circles here. I know it's not in the right place. That's why I made the post. The question I'm asking is, where is the right place to put it or what's a better way to accomplish performing the second action. Thanks